# Primitive space of connected Hopf algebras

Tags: hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a connected Hopf algebra. Let $C_1, C_2$ be two subcoalgebras of $H$.
Is $P(C_1+C_2)=P(C_1)+P(C_2)$?

Any comments are welcome.